# Capture OSX media control buttons in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, media-player

I would like my app to respond to the <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> keyboard media control buttons.

I am aware of this lovely library but it is not working in combination with Swift: https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I actually solved this problem myself just the other day. I wrote a [blog post](http://sernprogramming.com/blog/handling-media-key-events-in-swift/) on it, as well as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Serneum/b0ed0f75f3d0c6e4058a)

I'll embed the blog post and final code just in case the blog or Gist ever go away. **Note:** This is a very long post that goes into detail about how the class in constructed and what you can do to call other methods in your App's delegate. If all you want is the finished product (the MediaApplication class), head towards the bottom. It's just above the XML and the Info.plist informaton.

---

For starters, to get the key events from the media keys you need to create a class that extends `NSApplication`. This is as simple as

```
import Cocoa

class MediaApplication: NSApplication {
}
```

Next, we need to override the `sendEvent()` function

```
override func sendEvent(event: NSEvent) {
    if (event.type == .SystemDefined && event.subtype.rawValue == 8) {
        let keyCode = ((event.data1 & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16)
        let keyFlags = (event.data1 & 0x0000FFFF)
        // Get the key state. 0xA is KeyDown, OxB is KeyUp
        let keyState = (((keyFlags & 0xFF00) >> 8)) == 0xA
        let keyRepeat = (keyFlags & 0x1)
        mediaKeyEvent(Int32(keyCode), state: keyState, keyRepeat: Bool(keyRepeat))
    }

    super.sendEvent(event)
}
```

Now, I don't pretend to entirely understand what is going on here, but I think I have a decent idea. `NSEvent` objects contain several key properties: `type`, `subtype`, `data1`, and `data2`. `Type` and `subtype` are fairly self-explanatory, but `data1` and `data2` are extremely vague. Since the code only uses `data1`, that's what we'll be looking at. From what I can tell, `data1` contains all of the data surrounding a key event. That means it contains the key code and any key flags. It appears that key flags contain information about the key's state (Is the key pressed down? Has the key been released?) as well as whether or not the key is being held down and repeating the signal. I'm also guessing that the key code and key flags both take up half of the data contained in `data1` and the bitwise operations are separating that data out into appropriate variables. After we get the values we need, we call `mediaKeyEvent()` which I will get to in a moment. Regardless of what events get sent to our `MediaApplication`, we do want the default `NSApplication` to handle all events as well. To do this, we call `super.sendEvent(event)` at the end of the function. Now, let's take a look at `mediaKeyEvent()`.

```
func mediaKeyEvent(key: Int32, state: Bool, keyRepeat: Bool) {
    // Only send events on KeyDown. Without this check, these events will happen twice
    if (state) {
        switch(key) {
        case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
            // Do work
            break
        case NX_KEYTYPE_FAST:
            // Do work
            break
        case NX_KEYTYPE_REWIND:
            // Do work
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This is where things start to get fun. First things first, we only want to check what key is being pressed if `state` is true, which in this case is whenever the key is pressed down. Once we get into checking the keys, we look for `NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY`, `NX_KEYTYPE_FAST`, and `NX_KEYTYPE_REWIND`. If their functions aren't obvious, `NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY` is the play/pause key, `NX_KEYTYPE_FAST` is the next key, and `NX_KEYTYPE_REWIND` is the previous key. Right now, nothing happens when any of those keys is pressed down, so lets go over some possible logic. We'll start with a simple scenario.

```
case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
    print("Play")
    break
```

With this code in place, when your application detects that the play/pause key has been pressed you will see "Play" printed out to the console. Simple, right? Let's up the ante by calling functions in your application's `NSApplicationDelegate`. First we will assume that your `NSApplicationDelegate` has a function called `printMessage`. We will be modifying it as we go, so pay close attention to the changes. They will be minor, but the changes will impact how you call them from `mediaEventKey`.

```
func printMessage() {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

This is the simplest case. When `printMessage()` is called, you will see "Hello World" in your console. You can call this by calling `performSelector` on your `NSApplicationDelegate` which is accessible through the `MediaApplication`. `performSelector` takes in a `Selector` which is just the name of the function in your `NSApplicationDelegate`.

```
case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
    delegate!.performSelector("printMessage")
    break
```

Now, when your application detects that the play/pause key has been pressed, you will see "Hello World" printed to the console. Let's kick things up a notch with a new version of `printMessage` that takes in a parameter.

```
func printMessage(arg: String) {
    print(arg)
}
```

The idea is now that if `printMessage("Hello World")` is called, you will see "Hello World" in your console. We can now modify the `performSelector` call to handle passing in a parameter.

```
case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
    delegate!.performSelector("printMessage:", withObject: "Hello World")
    break
```

There are a few things to note about this change. First, it's important to notice the `:` that was added to the `Selector`. This separates the function name from the parameter when it gets sent to the delegate. How it works isn't too important to remember, but it's something along the lines of the delegate calling `printMessage:"Hello World"`. I'm fairly certain that is not 100% correct as it would likely use an object ID of some sort, but I haven't done any extensive digging into the specifics. Either way, the important thing to remember is to add `:` when passing in a parameter.. The second thing to note is that we added a `withObject` parameter. `withObject` takes an `AnyObject?` as a value. In this case, we just pass in a `String` because that's what `printMessage` is looking for. When your application detects that the play/pause key has been pressed, you should still see "Hello World" in the console. Let's look at one final use-case: a version of `printMessage` that takes in not one, but two parameters.

```
func printMessage(arg: String, _ arg2: String) {
    print(arg)
}
```

Now, if `printMessage("Hello",  "World")` is called, you will see "Hello World" in your console. We can now modify the `performSelector` call to handle passing in two parameters.

```
case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
    delegate!.performSelector("printMessage::", withObject: "Hello", withObject: "World")
    break
```

As before, there are two things to notice here. First, we now add two `:` to the end of the `Selector`. Like before, this is so that the delegate can pass information along that contains the parameters. At a very basic level, it would look something like `printMessage:"Hello":"World"`, but again I don't know what it really looks like at a deeper level. The second thing to notice is that we have added a second `withObject` parameter to the `performSelector` call. Like before, this `withObject` takes an `AnyObject?` as a value and we're passing in a `String` because that's what `printMessage` wants. When your application detects that the play/pause key has been pressed, you should still see "Hello World" in the console.

One final thing to note is that `performSelector` can only accept up to two parameters. I'd really like to see Swift add concepts like splatting or varargs so that this limitation eventually goes away, but for now just avoid trying to call functions that require more than two parameters.

This is what a very simple `MediaApplication` class that just prints out some text would look like once you are done with everything above:

```
import Cocoa

class MediaApplication: NSApplication {
    override func sendEvent(event: NSEvent) {
        if (event.type == .SystemDefined && event.subtype.rawValue == 8) {
            let keyCode = ((event.data1 & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16)
            let keyFlags = (event.data1 & 0x0000FFFF)
            // Get the key state. 0xA is KeyDown, OxB is KeyUp
            let keyState = (((keyFlags & 0xFF00) >> 8)) == 0xA
            let keyRepeat = (keyFlags & 0x1)
            mediaKeyEvent(Int32(keyCode), state: keyState, keyRepeat: Bool(keyRepeat))
        }

        super.sendEvent(event)
    }

    func mediaKeyEvent(key: Int32, state: Bool, keyRepeat: Bool) {
        // Only send events on KeyDown. Without this check, these events will happen twice
        if (state) {
            switch(key) {
            case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
                print("Play")
                break
            case NX_KEYTYPE_FAST:
                print("Next")
                break
            case NX_KEYTYPE_REWIND:
                print("Prev")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I should also add that, by default, your application is going to use the standard `NSApplication` when it runs. If you want to use the `MediaApplication` that this whole post is about, you'll need to go ahead and modify your application's `Info.plist` file. If you're in the graphical view, it will look something like this:

[image: Info.plist]
<sub>(source: [sernprogramming.com](https://sernprogramming.com/portfolio/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Info-plist-e1443001917118.png))</sub>

Otherwise, it will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string></string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1</string>
  <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
  <string>public.app-category.utilities</string>
  <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
  <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
  <key>LSUIElement</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
  <string>Copyright © 2015 Chris Rees. All rights reserved.</string>
  <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
  <string>MainMenu</string>
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
  <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In either case, you will want to change the `NSPrincipalClass` property. The new value will include you project's name, so it will be something like `Notify.MediaApplication`. Once you make the change, run your application and use those media keys!

Comment: hey @Serneum thanks for nice details.
Here is my problem: 
can we block this event for iTunes? actually whenever play key press it launch iTunes.

Comment: To handle iTunes launch on media key press. https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap

Comment: Nice solution but it doesn't work when you create the application programmatically (using main.swift instead of using storyboard or xib file)